# I am trying to Reduce check box width in grid but unable to reduce

Tags: checkbox, grid, width, acumatica-kb

I am trying to Reduce check box width in grid but unable to reduce

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

- You can reduce the width from the column's header (if it does not have AllowResize = False).
- The width can be automatically adjusted by clicking the |<->| icon from the grid's toolbar.
- Click on the top-left icon (which opens the hidden columns list) and then 'Reset to default) -> this will reset the column's list and also their size.
- If you have access as customizer, you can set the width for this column: I would recommend 30px

Comment: Hi Lucian, Thank you for quick help. Actually we want to set column with 8px due to we have added custom column. But I tried with all option above you given. I think acumatica setting minimum width, its overriding our given width so unable to reduce cell width 8px.

Comment: Lucian : As you said it's working Thanks!

Comment: @srinivasaraokota I am glad you've found what you need. If this answer helped you, please mark it as an answer. If you have more details to improve it, you can either write them in a comment and I'll edit my answer, or post your own answer, so others will know what to do. Thank you!

Comment: Click on the top-left icon (which opens the hidden columns list) and then 'Reset to default) -> this will reset the column's list and also their size.